# Derived Column Task

Tags: ssis

What is the purpose of Derived Column Task ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It allows you to add a derived (computed) column in a Data Flow task. It's a convenient way to compute an arbitrary expression for each row of a data source or intermediate result.